# Python - Decode Base64 string that is longer than the limit

Tags: python, base64, decode

In order to upload large csv files I have implemented a system that splits the file into smaller chunks, encodes those chunks and sends to the backend.
On the backend (PHP), I append all the base64 encoded data to a single file as I had planned to decode it all in python using a shell script.

This works great on small files but once I reach files that are over a certain limit (in my case 100mb), I fail to decode the entire file.
Here is my code

```py
def getDataFrameFromFile():
    # Read file in - which will be in base64url
    contents = ""
    with open(PATH + FILE_NAME) as f:
        contents = f.read()

    text = b64decode(contents).decode('utf-8')
    print("Length of text: ", len(contents))
    # Create pandas Dataframe, first column is time, second is raw
    DATA = StringIO(text)
    df = pd.read_csv(DATA, sep=',')
    return df
```

This is the output I got from the `print` statement: `Length of text:  69905200`.
I believe this is too large for function `b64decode` to handle in one call.

Is there a way I can split the base64 into smaller chunks, decode them and then join the data at the end?

I read somewhere that you can split base64 into strings of character length of `mod 3 = 0`. Is this true, if so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I read somewhere that you can split base64 into strings of character length of mod 3 = 0. Is this true, if so how would I do this?

This is indeed true ([an understanding of the way base64 encoding works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and a little math will tell you why, if you want to know). One really easy thing you can do is split your string into divisible-by-3-length-pieces you know you can decode, decode the pieces, and then concatenate them. I'm going to choose 15 as my piece length (you'll likely want to choose a much larger number that's divisible by 3). So, perhaps:

```
PIECESIZE=15
text = ''
while(len(contents) > 0):
  text += b64decode(contents[:PIECESIZE])
  contents = contents[PIECESIZE:]
```

Comment: What checks should I also be doing for padding? I implemented your code and got the error `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`

Comment: First, make sure PIECESIZE is divisible by three.
You can use the official base64 padding character, '=', and it will automatically be ignored by b64decode(). You can also use some other non-base64 character and strip it before you do the decode.